# using the result of wmic path system32 estimatedchargeremaining as a variable

Tags: batch-file, path, wmic, batterylevel, system32

Within a batch file I am running the command:

```
wmic path system32 estimatedchargeremaining
```

What I want to achieve is use the result of this to execute another command dependant on the result. For example if the output reads:

```
estimatedchargeremaining 
75
```

I want to use 75...not errorlevel 0

so the command to run there after would be something along the lines of:

```
    if estimatedchargeremaining LEQ 15 
*NEW COMMAND*

if estimatedchargeremining GTR 99
*NEW COMMAND*
```

But as the returned value does not meet either of those no command will be executed.

I hope this is clear enough. Unfortunately as I am on a different computer at the moment I cant show you what I have already. But can make this available later on if needs be.

Cheers Guys

Here is formatted code:

```
@echo ON 
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ( 
  'wmic path win32_battery estimatedchargeremaining /value^|find "="' ) do ( 
    if %%a LEQ 15 echo DEVCON ENABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2" GOTO END 
    if %%a GTR 99 echo DEVCON DISABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2" GOTO END 
) 
:end
PAUSE
```

This is the code I am now trying to use following matts suggestion:

```
    @echo ON
cd c:/windows/system32
setlocal enableextensions

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
  'wmic path win32_battery get estimatedchargeremaining /value^|find "="'
) do (
  if %%a LEQ 15 (GOTO :ENABLE) else goto :DISABLE0
:DISABLE0
  if %%a GEQ 99 (GOTO :DISABLE)
)

:ENABLE
DEVCON ENABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2" 

:DISABLE
DEVCON DISABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2" 


:END
PAUSE
```

when i execute the batch file, this is what is happening:

```
C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop>cd c:/windows/system32

c:\Windows\System32>setlocal enableextensions

c:\Windows\System32>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('wmic path win32_battery g et estimatedchargeremaining /value|find "="') do ( if %a LEQ 15 (GOTO :ENABLE )  else goto :DISABLE0  if %a GEQ 99 (GOTO :DISABLE ) )

c:\Windows\System32>(  LEQ 15 (GOTO :ENABLE )  else goto :DISABLE0  GEQ 99 (GOTO :DISABLE ) )

c:\Windows\System32>DEVCON ENABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2" ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2                                   : Enabled 1 device(s) enabled.

c:\Windows\System32>DEVCON DISABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2" ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2                                   : Disabled 1 device(s) disabled.

c:\Windows\System32>PAUSE Press any key to continue . . .
```

I cant work out why the "GOTO's" are being ignored and both commands are being executed thus cancelling each other out?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt.

I have used what you suggested as follows...

    @echo ON
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
  'wmic path win32_battery estimatedchargeremaining /value^|find "="'
) do (
  if %%a LEQ 15 echo DEVCON ENABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2"
GOTO END
  if %%a GTR 99 echo DEVCON DISABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2"
GOTO END
)

:end
PAUSE

All I am getting is  "Invalid Verb" at the end?

Comment: PS....sorry about the format....I cant post it any other way for another 4 hours??

Comment: I edited your question to include the modified code you posted in your comment. Easier to read that way. Invalid verb is a wmic error. what do you get if you just run `wmic path win32_battery get` ? You can always edit your question to add new relevant info. The more specific the better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I don't have a laptop here to test with but it should be close.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
  'wmic path win32_battery get estimatedchargeremaining /value^|find "="'
) do (
  if %%a LEQ 15 echo do something
  if %%a GTR 99 echo do something else
)
```

Comment: Hi, never mind the invalid verb, I sorted that. However....I am now using this......

@echo ON
cd c:/windows/system32
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
  'wmic path win32_battery get estimatedchargeremaining /value^|find "="'
) do (
  if %%a LEQ 15 GOTO ENABLE 

  if %%a GEQ 99 GOTO DISABLE 
)

:ENABLE
DEVCON ENABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2" 

:DISABLE
DEVCON DISABLE "@ACPI\ACPI0003\2&DABA3FF&2" 


:END
PAUSE

but when i execute the batch file both the enable and disable commands are executing thus cancelling each other out?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this question was asked but I had a similar problem and google led me here. So here's my solution:

```
powershell -command "(Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery).EstimatedChargeRemaining" >batdat.txt
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (batdat.txt) DO set /A var=%%x
rem: After that, you can use var for whatever conditions you want.
```

Note: This solution involves using an entirely different command because the above mentioned one just gives the numeric value unlike `wmic path system32 estimatedchargeremaining` which has text in its output which complicates everything else. If you have to use the other command I have no idea.